# Data graphing with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

A line chart that updates every couple of seconds and doesn't need the page to be refreshed would be the goal (it would get the info from a separate file that updates on a server). Are any JavaScript libs(other than JQuery) that will make this is easy? Could anyone show an example on a webpage?

The data gets updated on a fixed interval. If possible the preference would be to use only CSS HTML5 and javascript.

Comment: I have used `CanvasJS` for real-time plotting before, and its quite nice and easy. http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-dynamic-chart/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several charting libraries that can be used : [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/), [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and the one mentioned by others. These libraries are quite easy to use and well-documented (lets say 1 on the difficulty scale).

AFAIK, these libs are not "real-time" because they don't give the possibility to add new points on the fly. To add new point, you need to redraw the full chart. But I think this is not a problem because redrawing the chart is fast. I've made some tries with gRaphael and I didn't notice any problem with this approach. If you update rate is 10s that should work ok (but it may depends on the complexity of your charts).

If redrawing the full chart is a problem, you may have to develop a chart by yourself with a vector graphics lib like [Raphael](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) or [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/). That will be a bit harder than using a charting lib but should be feasible. (Let say 5 on the difficulty scale).

As you are getting the data on a fixed intervall, you can use a regular ajax lib. jQuery is ok for me but there are some other choices. That may not be the best choice for a non-fixed interval and in this case you may have to look at something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) but it would have consequences on the server side too.

Note1: Raphael, gRaphael and Highcharts are not purely HTML5 but SVG/VML but I guess this is an acceptable choice too.

Note2: it seems that Highchart doesn't require to redraw the chart when inserting new points. See http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#live-charts

Comment: I also initially tried to find solutions to "not redraw the entire chart every time" for performance reasons. But then I realised that this is a fallacy. Any solution must redraw the chart for every frame. Think about it: how does your monitor work? It continually refreshes itself from scratch, it doesn't move pixels around. Therefore any charting library that allows you to "not redraw the chart" is just providing an abstraction for you. This abstraction is convenient and desireable; nevertheless performance-wise it is still redrawing the chart in the background for every frame.

Comment: @Fletch I think the difference is that some re-draws are less expensive because they're done at a lower level in the browser's architecture. For example, I think shifting all the pixels on a large canvas to the left would be more expensive than shifting the actual canvas to the left using CSS. Maybe not though, just a thought.

Comment: I have a requirement to plot up to say a max of 500,000 data points, streamed at a rate of about 65,000 points every second, however the chart should re re-rendered / refreshed every 100ms (ie say incorporating 6500 new points every 100ms). Is this possible?. Basically, we have a real-time acquisition system which we want to appear as presented in near 'real-time'.

Comment: Another live demo with dynamically adding points in HighCharts: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Answer (score 35):

I would suggest [Smoothie Charts](http://smoothiecharts.org/).

[image]

It's very simple to use, easily and widely configurable, and does a great job of streaming real time data.

There's a [builder that lets you explore the options and generate code](http://smoothiecharts.org/builder/).

*Disclaimer:* I am a contributor to the library.

Comment: Really nice, although it would also be nicer if it would be able to also plot static data and even plot dynamic data over static data, for example yesterday's evolution of some price and today's current evolution, so it is easy to compare.

Comment: This is gorgeous and really easy to use.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Open source (although a license is required for commercial websites), cross device/browser, fast.

Answer (score 5):

Several things that might help you:

Canvas Express is a powerful charting library :  http://canvasxpress.org/

Here you can find a tutorial about rolling your own equation based graphs:   http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-graphing-an-equation/

Using a canvas solution is very easy, You can retrieve your periodic data for the graph using ajax, and redraw the graph every time you retrieve new data.
Since it's all client side you won't have to refresh the page.

If you knwo your way aroudn javascript and ajax, then it's gonna be a medium difficulty. If you don't then you'll probably have to post some more questions on Stack Ovreflow to help you with the parts you get stuck with.

Answer (score 4):

[Flotr2](http://humblesoftware.com/flotr2/documentation) and [Envision](http://humblesoftware.com/envision/) are options. Flotr2 has a real time example on the doco page I linked. Envision is a bit tougher to get started with, so try Flotr2.

Comment: I'd recommend this one too. It's a very solid lib.

Comment: The flotr2 example is not real-time... it's just redrawing the whole chart repeatedly.

Comment: @tybro0103 Exactly, that is real-time. At first I thought like you but then I realised that this is the only way to do it. How does a movie work? Flash through 25 different pictures in a second and it looks like motion. How does a monitor work? Continually redrawing the pixels according to what is now meant to be shown, the speed of this redrawing is measured in Hertz. You can't move a pixel on a chart. You have to redraw the chart with the new locations. Even if the library abstracts it and makes you feel like you are moving pixels, it's still just redrawing behind the scenes.

Comment: @Fletch You're right in that it does have to redraw the whole thing in order to show new data. However, what I meant to say is that it reloads the whole data set repeatedly. Check the source and you'll see that the code `for (...) {data.push(...)}` is executed each time the chart renders. This is wasting CPU and can be a real problem when there are thousands of data points per second. A better real-time chart will allow you to simply append a single data point at a time, rather than reset the entire dataset each time you have a new point.

Comment: SmoothieCharts does it right: http://smoothiecharts.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

In order to complete this thread, I would suggest you to look into:

### [d3.js](http://d3js.org)

This is a library that helps with tons of javascript visualizations. However the learning curve is quite steep.

### [nvd3.js](http://nvd3.org/)

A library that makes it easy to create some d3.js visualizations (with limitations, of course).

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to look at [CanvasJS Chart](http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-dynamic-chart/) which is built on top of HTML5 Canvas Element. It renders really fast and can be updated every 50-100 milliseconds without getting into memory issues.

[Full disclosure: I am part of the team]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way may be to use [plotti.co](http://plotti.co) - the microservice I created exactly for this. It depends on how you get the data, but general usage pattern is including an SVG image into your html like

```
<object data="http://plotti.co/FSktKOvATQ8H/plot.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

and feeding your data in a GET request to your hash (or using a `(new Image(1,1)).src=...` JavaScript method from same or any other page) like this:

http://plotti.co/FSktKOvATQ8H?d=1,2,3

setting it up locally is also straightforward

Answer (score 1):

You get the data from server, update your previously available datasetand then probably use one of the freely available libraries to draw the graph (eg: http://www.rgraph.net)

Things you might want to considering : If your chart is represents a state , get only the new data with xhr , update data on client and draw .

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rgraph.net/ is excellent for graph and charts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a gist I discovered for real-time charts in [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/):
https://gist.github.com/arisetyo/5985848

ChartJS looks like it's simple to use and looks nice.

Also there's [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/), a more sophisticated library for enterprise use, with a demo of real time here: 
http://www.fusioncharts.com/explore/real-time-charts

**EDIT**
I also started using Rickshaw for real time graphs and it's easy to use and pretty customizable:
http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/

Comment: Awesome find for the gist, man!

Answer (score 1):

This thread is perhaps very very old now. But want to share these results for someone who see this thread. Ran a comparison betn. Flotr2, ChartJS, highcharts asynchronously. Flotr2 seems to be the quickest. Tested this by passing a new data point every 50ms upto 1000 data points totally. Flotr2 was the quickest for me though it appears to be redrawing charts regularly.

http://jsperf.com/async-charts-test/2

Answer (score 0):

You might also give Meteor Charts a try, it's super fast (html5 canvas), has lots of tutorials, and is also well documented.  Live updates work really well.  You just update the model and run chart.draw() to re-render the scene graph.  Here's a demo:

http://meteorcharts.com/demo

Answer (score 0):

Addition from 2015 
As far as I know there is still no runtime oriented line chart lib. I mean chart which behaviors "request new points each N sec", "purge old data" you could setup "declarative" way.

Instead there is graphite api http://graphite-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/  for server side, and number of client side plugins that uses it.  But actually they are quite limited, absent advanced features that we like: data scroller, range charts, axeX segmentation on phases, etc..

It seems there is fundamental difference between tasks "show me reach chart" and have "real time chart".