# Are there any side-effects of using public libraries in coding

Tags: javascript

I'm considering to build a real time line chart.
Been searching around find suggestions providing outside libraries to code
[like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502827/real-time-data-graphing-on-a-line-chart-with-html5)
by simply download and configure my goal will be achieved.

But,it is also possible to make a real time line chart by write some ajax,css,html etc. by myself,it will take more time(due to my unprofessional skill)

What are the pros and cons of using others libraries and write myself?

Comment: Would you like to grow your own tree, cut it, shape it, make a dinner table. Or just go to IKEA and buy it from there and use it at the same day?

Comment: The popular libraries are not only well done and efficient for the more part, but also supported, maintained, and tested. It's like buying a car vs making your own car (just in this case the car is free).

Comment: @Teomanshipahi the IKEA way is so convenient,so kinda of feeling unreal.May it cause lagging? security concern?or sth else

Comment: @orz eventually you will end up with another dependencies. All we are. Even if you will make your own real time line chart, tomorrow you will have to use 3rd party image slider, another day modal dialog box, next day something else. You will use bootstrap, angularjs, jquery... All those are dependencies and I assume you will not end up creating another jquery or web framework because you want your own :) My suggestion keep your energy to create something does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One disadvantage in the past to using JavaScript libraries is that the libraries tend to be rather large and perhaps include quite a lot of code that your individual web pages don't actually use.

An advantage to using a library that already handles 90% of the processing that you need to have run means that you only need to write that remaining 10%.

Comment: will it cause webpage loading slowly?

Comment: yes..sometimes it happens because you use a code that is not designed by you..if you design it by yourself then you take care that the code is optimized..so, there are chances...reply me..ok and accept my answer too.